# Kivy: How to first initialize the class and then build it?

Tags: python, kivy

In my kivy/python program I add a row at the press of a button. In the **init** function of my row I create variables which I need in the kivy file of the row. It doesn't work, I guess because first the row is being build, and only then is the init funtion called. Is there a way to change the order?
Thanks in advance!

I add my row like this:
`self.ids.container.add_widget(Row(link))`

Some code to clarify:

main.py

```
class AllitemsScreen(Screen):

    def AddItem(self, link):
        row = Row(link)
        self.ids.container.add_widget(row)


class Row(BoxLayout):

    def __init__(self, link,  **kwargs):

        super(Row, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        item_dict[self] = Item(link)
        self.image_source = item_dict[self].image
        self.itemname = item_dict[self].name
```

kiv file:

```
Row>:
    orientation: "horizontal"

    BoxLayout:
        orientation: "vertical"
        font_name:"Nunito"
        Label:
            text: root.itemname
            font_name:"Nunito"
        Button:
            id: root.count
            text: "delete item"
            on_press: root.delete_item()
    Image:
        source: root.image_source
        width: 100
```

So when AddItem is called, a new row is created. I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "C:\Users\caspe\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\kivy\lang\builder.py", line 249, in create_handler
     return eval(value, idmap), bound_list
   File "C:\Users\caspe\Documents\Casper app\myapp.kv", line 124, in <module>
     source: root.image_source
   File "kivy\weakproxy.pyx", line 32, in kivy.weakproxy.WeakProxy.__getattr__
 AttributeError: 'Row' object has no attribute 'image_source'

 During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

 Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "C:\Users\caspe\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\kivy\lang\builder.py", line 692, in _apply_rule
     rctx['ids'])
   File "C:\Users\caspe\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\kivy\lang\builder.py", line 254, in create_handler
     cause=tb)
 kivy.lang.builder.BuilderException: Parser: File "C:\Users\caspe\Documents\Casper app\myapp.kv", line 124:     
 ...
     122:            on_press: root.delete_item()
     123:    Image:
 >>  124:        source: root.image_source
     125:        width: 100
     126:
 ...
 AttributeError: 'Row' object has no attribute 'image_source'
   File "C:\Users\caspe\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\kivy\lang\builder.py", line 249, in create_handler
     return eval(value, idmap), bound_list
   File "C:\Users\caspe\Documents\Casper app\myapp.kv", line 124, in <module>
     source: root.image_source
   File "kivy\weakproxy.pyx", line 32, in kivy.weakproxy.WeakProxy.__getattr__


 During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

 Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "main.py", line 95, in <module>
     MyApp().run()
   File "C:\Users\caspe\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\kivy\app.py", line 855, in run
     runTouchApp()
   File "C:\Users\caspe\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\kivy\base.py", line 504, in runTouchApp
     EventLoop.window.mainloop()
   File "C:\Users\caspe\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\kivy\core\window\window_sdl2.py", line 747, in mainloop
     self._mainloop()
   File "C:\Users\caspe\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\kivy\core\window\window_sdl2.py", line 479, in _mainloop
     EventLoop.idle()
   File "C:\Users\caspe\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\kivy\base.py", line 342, in idle
     self.dispatch_input()
   File "C:\Users\caspe\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\kivy\base.py", line 327, in dispatch_input
     post_dispatch_input(*pop(0))
   File "C:\Users\caspe\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\kivy\base.py", line 233, in post_dispatch_input
     listener.dispatch('on_motion', etype, me)
   File "kivy\_event.pyx", line 707, in kivy._event.EventDispatcher.dispatch
   File "C:\Users\caspe\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\kivy\core\window\__init__.py", line 1402, in on_motion
     self.dispatch('on_touch_down', me)
   File "kivy\_event.pyx", line 707, in kivy._event.EventDispatcher.dispatch
   File "C:\Users\caspe\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\kivy\core\window\__init__.py", line 1418, in on_touch_down
     if w.dispatch('on_touch_down', touch):
   File "kivy\_event.pyx", line 707, in kivy._event.EventDispatcher.dispatch
   File "C:\Users\caspe\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\kivy\uix\screenmanager.py", line 1191, in on_touch_down
     return super(ScreenManager, self).on_touch_down(touch)
   File "C:\Users\caspe\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\kivy\uix\widget.py", line 549, in on_touch_down
     if child.dispatch('on_touch_down', touch):
   File "kivy\_event.pyx", line 707, in kivy._event.EventDispatcher.dispatch
   File "C:\Users\caspe\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\kivy\uix\relativelayout.py", line 288, in on_touch_down
     ret = super(RelativeLayout, self).on_touch_down(touch)
   File "C:\Users\caspe\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\kivy\uix\widget.py", line 549, in on_touch_down
     if child.dispatch('on_touch_down', touch):
   File "kivy\_event.pyx", line 707, in kivy._event.EventDispatcher.dispatch
   File "C:\Users\caspe\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\kivy\uix\widget.py", line 549, in on_touch_down
     if child.dispatch('on_touch_down', touch):
   File "kivy\_event.pyx", line 707, in kivy._event.EventDispatcher.dispatch
   File "C:\Users\caspe\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\kivy\uix\behaviors\button.py", line 151, in on_touch_down
     self.dispatch('on_press')
   File "kivy\_event.pyx", line 703, in kivy._event.EventDispatcher.dispatch
   File "kivy\_event.pyx", line 1214, in kivy._event.EventObservers.dispatch
   File "kivy\_event.pyx", line 1098, in kivy._event.EventObservers._dispatch
   File "C:\Users\caspe\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\kivy\lang\builder.py", line 64, in custom_callback
     exec(__kvlang__.co_value, idmap)
   File "C:\Users\caspe\Documents\Casper app\myapp.kv", line 49, in <module>
     on_press: root.manager.screens[1].AddItem(input.text), app.AddImage(), root.manager.screens[1].AddRow(), app.ShowPopup()
   File "main.py", line 47, in AddItem
     row = Row(link)
   File "main.py", line 57, in __init__
     super(Row, self).__init__(**kwargs)
   File "C:\Users\caspe\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\kivy\uix\boxlayout.py", line 145, in __init__
     super(BoxLayout, self).__init__(**kwargs)
   File "C:\Users\caspe\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\kivy\uix\layout.py", line 76, in __init__
     super(Layout, self).__init__(**kwargs)
   File "C:\Users\caspe\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\kivy\uix\widget.py", line 361, in __init__
     rule_children=rule_children)
   File "C:\Users\caspe\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\kivy\uix\widget.py", line 469, in apply_class_lang_rules
     rule_children=rule_children)
   File "C:\Users\caspe\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\kivy\lang\builder.py", line 538, in apply
     rule_children=rule_children)
   File "C:\Users\caspe\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\kivy\lang\builder.py", line 707, in _apply_rule
     e), cause=tb)
 kivy.lang.builder.BuilderException: Parser: File "C:\Users\caspe\Documents\Casper app\myapp.kv", line 124:     
 ...
     122:            on_press: root.delete_item()
     123:    Image:
 >>  124:        source: root.image_source
     125:        width: 100
     126:
 ...
 BuilderException: Parser: File "C:\Users\caspe\Documents\Casper app\myapp.kv", line 124:
 ...
     122:            on_press: root.delete_item()
     123:    Image:
 >>  124:        source: root.image_source
     125:        width: 100
     126:
 ...
 AttributeError: 'Row' object has no attribute 'image_source'
   File "C:\Users\caspe\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\kivy\lang\builder.py", line 249, in create_handler
     return eval(value, idmap), bound_list
   File "C:\Users\caspe\Documents\Casper app\myapp.kv", line 124, in <module>
     source: root.image_source
   File "kivy\weakproxy.pyx", line 32, in kivy.weakproxy.WeakProxy.__getattr__

   File "C:\Users\caspe\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\kivy\lang\builder.py", line 692, in _apply_rule
     rctx['ids'])
   File "C:\Users\caspe\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\kivy\lang\builder.py", line 254, in create_handler
     cause=tb)
```

Comment: What does "doesn't work" mean? Does it throw an error? Does it not do what you expect? Also, can you add code to reproduce the issue you are having?

Comment: Code and clarification added

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the superclass' `__init__` method (`BoxLayout.__init__`) is trying to access the `Row.image_source` attribute, which does not exist at the time you call it.

To fix that, just move the `super` call so `BoxLayout.__init__` is called after you declared all attributes:

```py
class Row(BoxLayout):
    def __init__(self, link,  **kwargs):
        item_dict[self] = Item(link)
        self.image_source = item_dict[self].image
        self.itemname = item_dict[self].name
        super(Row, self).__init__(**kwargs)
```

Answer (score 4):

The kv language file is processed when you call `super(Row, self).__init__(**kwargs)` by the `Widget.__init__` function. While you could just do your initialisation before calling `super` it will not enable all of kivys features esp. changes of attributes will not propagate properly. The kivy way is to define your properties as [kivy properties](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/gettingstarted/properties.html), in your code this would probably be something like:

```
class Row(BoxLayout):
    itemname = StringProperty()
    image_source = StringProperty()

    ...
```

Otherwise changes to itemname or image_source will not change the text of the label. Because kivy properties have default values, it doesn't throw an error anymore if you first call `super` and then initialize your values, although first initializing is probably more efficient.